# Android ListView only shows one item at a time

Tags: java, android

My program is that when a user enteres some information and clicks the "Submit" button, this data will be stored in a separate activity's list View.I have a Shared Preferences incorporated so that the data will be stored. The problem is that only one piece of information gets stored at a time. If I enter a new piece of data, the previous one is overwritten.

```
public class PreviousPractices extends Activity {
int minutes,hours;
String description;
String date;
ListView practiceList;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.previous_practices_layout);

    practiceList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.practiceList);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listItems);
    practiceList.setAdapter(adapter);
    getIntents();
    LoadPreferences();
}

public void getIntents(){
    if (getIntent().getExtras() == null) {

    }
    else {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        hours = extras.getInt("Hours");
        minutes = extras.getInt("Minutes");
        description = extras.getString("Description");
        date = extras.getString("dateOfPractice");

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        SavePreferences("LISTS", date);
    }


}
```

Right now I'm only working with the date to simplify things. I'm not sure what the issue is, and I'd appreciate some help.

Comment: what listItems is made of? it seems you don't add anything

Comment: At first I added a String to listItems (listItems.add(String something) )but then the entry showed up two times in the ListView so I removed that line and now it correctly shows up once.

Comment: It appears that you're using the same key each time to save your date to Preferences. If so, then, yes, each save will just overwrite the previous one. Have you considered using a database instead? Using Preferences for something like this is going to be unwieldy.